# Routing issue in mvc with constraint attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i'm confused of making route need help!.
i put the code (below) in route config but i didn't know why Image action not perform to what i expect.

```
         routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Browse",
            url: "{action}/{*path}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Sample", action = "browse"},
            constraints: new { action = "Browse|Image" }
        );
```

when i put to window.location.href = 'localhost:11934/browse/a'  it works, but when i change browse 'localhost:11934/image/a' to image in does not.

what was the problem with that? someone give me some link on how to used constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`please refer this like`
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs 
http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/route-constraints-in-mvc.html 
[How do I use constraints in ASP.net MVC 4 RouteConfig.cs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651208/how-do-i-use-constraints-in-asp-net-mvc-4-routeconfig-cs)